# Relative extrema - calculus

Tags: calculus

You have opened a shoe factory and  you're trying to figure out the amount in thousands of pairs of shoes to produce in order to optimize your profit.

Suppose a wholesaler is willing to pay $\$10$ for every pair of shoe sold. After consulting a financial expert, you realize that your average cost is given as $y =x^2 -6x+15$. Where $x$ is given as the amount of shoes to produce in thousands

a. If you are restricted by the market to produce a maximum of $4000$ pairs of shoes, how many shoes do you need to produce in order to optimise your profit.

b. Will your answer in (a) above change if you're not restricted?

Comment: So what have you tried or what is your question? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I really don't get the concept on how to go about it.

Comment: Finding profit, TR and TC

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose a wholesaler is willing to pay $10 for every pair of shoe sold. After consulting a financial expert, you realize that your average cost is given as y =x^2 -6x+15. Where x is given as the amount of shoes to produce in thousands

I'm assuming the average cost is *per pair* (with $x$ in thousands). In that case, the production of $x$ pairs of shoes (with $x$ in thousands) gives you a profit of:
$$\mbox{Profit} = \underbrace{10x}_{\mbox{TR}}-\underbrace{x\left( x^2 -6x+15 \right)}_{\mbox{TC}}$$
You can now simplify and find the extreme values via the derivative.

Comment: Kindly help me with the b.

Comment: @EmmlTajumba What did you find for (a)?

Comment: a. I got the maximum pair of shoes to be produced to be 3,530

Comment: So you found an optimum slightly above 3,500 which is still under the restriction of 4,000; so this remains the optimal amount even if you are allowed to go over 4,000.

Comment: Exactly.. That's what I did.

Comment: @EmmlTajumba So there you have it then! If the optimal amount would have been over 4,000; you would probably have to pick 4,000 _with_ the restriction and the global optimal amount in the _unrestricted_ case.